# Sass selector as parameter in Mixin

Tags: sass

Im trying to create a Sass Mixin where a selector can be passed in otherwise default the 'img' tag, was hoping something like this would work

```
@mixin image-move($image: "img"){
  ##{$image}{transition:all .2s ease;}
  &:hover ##{$image}{margin-top:-5px;}
}

#header{
  @include image-move("img.main");
}
```

but its just silently failing not producing any CSS

Comment: I cannot reproduce:  your code generates CSS just fine:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/d445ba42563ec9d906c0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert the `@include` inside a selector (and interpolation requires a single `#` character)

```
@mixin image-move($image: "img"){
  #{$image}{transition:all .2s ease;}
  &:hover #{$image}{margin-top:-5px;}
}

div {
  @include image-move("img.main");
}
```

Comment: Yes the single # worked thanx